# How can i do better with images in android

Tags: android, image

I have images (Soccer Jersey) for EPL,Laliga,Bundes Liga and Serie A for Home,Away and Third-Kits.
So I want to show each team Jeysey in Detail as Home,Away and Third Kits.
Images are too much..for four League.
So i want to code for Only JerseyDetail.java and how can i do with that four league jerseys.Images are stored under @drawable.Is there any solutions for better performance with images and how to manipulate for that process.Please give me advices.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Shakeeb Ayaz                                                                                               I have to bind images in JerseyDetail.java.First think EPL has 20 teams, 3 types of jerseys(Home,Away and Third Kits).So one team has 3 jerseys.I want to bind that 3 jerseies to each team.I don't want to code many activities for each team.I want to bind their respective jersey drawable to JerseyDetail.java.I have to bind for other 3 leagues(Laliga,SerieA and Bundesliga).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following solution,

Basically we get the TextView object of the title in ActionBar, set it's max lines attribute to 2:

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title","id","android");
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
title.setSingleLine(false);
title.setMaxLines(2);
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
```

Then we can set a long title to the ActionBar where the text will be displayed as two lines:

```
getActionBar().setSubTitle("... your long title here ...");
```

Original source:

[Show multiple lines of title in Android ActionBar](http://hkdevtips.blogspot.com/2014/11/show-multiple-lines-of-title-in-android.html)